# javascript sequential dropdowns in form, to change URL value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a php-file: export.php , in which a form, with select dropdowns.

dd1 & dd2, where on selecting dd1, option-list of dd2 gets populated from sql table.

JS function:

```
function reload(form) {
        var val = form.cat.options[form.cat.options.selectedIndex].value;
        self.location = 'export.php?cat=' + val;
}

<form>

<!------------- dd1 -------------->
<select name="category" onchange="reload(this.form)">
<option>a</option>
<option>b</option>
<option>c</option>
<option>d</option>
</select>

<!--------- dd2 -------------->
<select name="subcategory">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
</select>
```

what i want is the URL like : 
    export.php?cat=a&subcat=1 
when i select an option from dd2, after selecting dd1 option.

Currently its changing to: export.php?cat=a only.

Please help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

$( "select[name=category],select[name=subcategory]" ).change(function() {

  var cat= $("select[name=category] option:selected").text();
  var subcat= $("select[name=subcategory] option:selected").text();

  var url = 'export.php?cat='+cat+'&subcat='+subcat;

  console.log(url);
});

});
```

You also have to remove

```
onchange="reload(this.form)
```

on ddl1 because it does a relocation and this will make a new request!

If you want to do a relocation only if a value in ddl1 and ddl2 is selected.
I would use default values for both dropdownlists like

> --choose--

Then you can check in the onchange handler (Pseudo code)

```
if (ddl1.selectValue!= --choose-- and  ddl2.selectValue!= --choose--){
window.location = url;
}
```

Comment: Both dropdowns getting reset automatically. Any guess ?

Comment: I told you to remove this: onchange="reload(this.form)

Comment: <form><select name="category">
<option value="aaaaaaa">aaaaaaa</option>
<option value="bbbbbbbb">bbbbbbbb</option>
<option value="ccccccccc">ccccccccc</option>
</select>

<br/><br/>

<select name="subcategory">
<option value="11">11</option>
<option value="22">22</option>
<option value="33">33</option>
</select>
</form>

Comment: Tested with this n found, its getting RESET, automatically. M surprised.

Comment: self.location was causing, dropdowns to reset. Removed it & DONE. Thanks TONS.

Comment: I told you, marked the answer as an answer if it helped you. Thanks